# several charts in one csv python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First of all let me thank you for your great help here. I am a silent follower of many items and they held me much to get better in python pandas.

To my question:
I do have a csv file including several information:

[image]

In a first step to plot the relevant data I used he following command

```
pd.read_csv(str(files_NOK[i]),delimiter=";",decimal=",",skiprows=278,usecols=range(3))
```

After doing this I focus as a first step to plot the data I am interested, which start from row=278. This is absolutely fine, however I try to find the corresponding `XMAX` or `XMIN` or `YMAX` or `YMIN` etc, but I really don't know what to do. I also tried to open the file in a different way:

```
pd.read_csv("file Name",sep="delimiter",decimal=",",skip_blank_lines=True,header=None, engine="python")
```

If I use this command I can see all the information, but I cannot plot the data and find for `XMIN`.
Is there anyone who can give me an advice, i.e. to plot the region of interest and to find the specific value for lets say `XMIN` or `YMIN`?

That would be great

Comment: It's not clear how you'd go about parsing your input data. It looks like 3 or 4 different data sets separated by arbitrary whitespace with a mix of horizontal and vertical orientation. Is that intentional? I would take the time to clean up the structure before attempting to do anything.

Comment: Dear Plasma, the issue is that these csv files are coming from a machine, i.e. I do have thousands of csv data with this kind of format. You are right, there are several kind of charts and that is my issue

Answer (score 1):

After long searching and try and error process, I found the solution, at least a working solution for me.

For those who might have the same issue:
it helps focus on the region you are interested and load these regions into panda.
For example I am interesed in the region beginning from row=10 to row=20, then I would use

```
df_NOK_EOS.append(pd.read_csv(str(files_NOK[i]),skiprows=69,nrows=4,delimiter=";",decimal=","))
```